# Existence of Adjoint on infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H_1, H_2$ be a Hilbert spaces. For $T\in L(H_1, H_2)$, the Hilbert adjoint operator $T^*$ of $T$ is defined as the operator $T^* : H_2 \to H_1$ such that for all $x\in H_1$ and $y\in H_2$,

$$\langle x, Ty\rangle  = \langle T^*x,y\rangle. $$
However, the definition itself doesn't seem to guarantee the existence of such operator $T^*$. So how do I prove such operator exists and is unique?

Comment: Do you know how we would define adjoints on general infinite dimension spaces? It is not how you learn it in the finite dimensional case. Once you know this definition, you can probably see where the adjoint comes from.

Comment: no sir, but it may be defined as it is function which satisfies the finite dimensional deginition

Comment: Don't call me sir, I may be younger than you, my friend. The adjoint of a matrix is a matrix, but the adjoint of a linear transformation $T : X \to Y$ between Banach spaces, is a transformation $T^* : Y^* \to X^*$, ( where $*$ denotes  the dual space, the space of linear functionals on the space) , which satisfies the relation $x^*(Ty) = T^*(x^*(y))$, for all $x^* \in X^*$, and all $y \in Y$. In finite dimensions, it turns out that $X^*$ and $X$ coincide, and if $X \cong Y$, then everything sinks back to the finite dimensional case. By the way, I'm twelve, so sir, I hope you are satisfied.

Comment: You are welcome, my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things called adjoint in linear algebra, so your question is not quite clear.

This being said the basic definition of the adjoint of a linear map $f:V\to W$ is the map $f^*:W^*\to V^*$ defined by $\alpha\mapsto\alpha\circ f$ for $\alpha\in W^*$. It only uses composition of linear maps, which is defined in all linear algebra settings, so the question of dimension really does not play a role at all.